# Knockout Js: Get Table row Index value of drop down subscribe

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using Knockout JS. while in the subscribe function of dropdown. I need to get the index of selected dropdown.

where as dropdown is inside table(ie foreach tr)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody  data-bind="foreach: Rows">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <select data-bind="options: Materials, value: selectedMaterial,attr:{index:$(index)}"></select>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
    this.selectedMaterial.subscribe(function(data){
       // I need to get the index value of the selectedMaterial

       // i try to get like following code but its not working
          var k =$(this).attr("index"); 
    });
```

Comment: What do you want to do after the index? Why don't you get index from the Materials collection `Materials.indexOf(data)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible for KO to do that in subscribe function. You should try another way like handle change event.

```
<select data-bind="event: {change: selectChanged}"... />

yourViewModel.selectChanged = function(data, event){
     var k = $(event.target).attr("index"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use data-bind to set the id of the element and then use jQuery to get the value out:

```
        <select data-bind="options: Materials, value: selectedMaterial,attr:{index:$(index), id: 'dropdown' + $index }"></select>

$('#dropDown' + theIndexOfTheTable).prop('selectedIndex');
```

This does presume that you will know the index of the table that you are processing.

Comment: In this , "theIndexOfTheTable" is the value which i need to find

Comment: Ah, right, I thought that you might know the index of the table, but not the dropdown.